# Parsing array objects in js objects to xml not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, xml, xml-parsing

Hey I'm trying to parse a javascript object to xml string in node.js app. I'm using the npm package  `json2xml` like this

```js
json2xml(jsonObject, { header: true });
```

my issue is that when there's an array object it will parse it like this:

```js
root: {
    foo: [
        {
            bar: 'a',
        },
        {
            bar: 'b',
        },
    ],
};
```

```xml
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar>a</bar>
        <bar>a</bar>
    </foo>
```

and not like this:

```xml
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar>a</bar>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <bar>b</bar>
    </foo>
</root>
```

as I wish it did. Do you have any suggestions or any other libraries I can use to fix this issue?

I've tried couple of other libraries: `jstoxml`, `@javadev/xmltojson`, `fast-xml-parser`, that didn't fix the issue. I'm thinking to write my own jsToXml parser xD

Comment: It's working perfectly well.  The structure of your desired output simply does not match that of the provided JSON.  See [@Pippo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76000806/290085) (+1) for the JSON that would match your target XML.

Answer (score 1):

The object should be composed like that:

```
{root: [{foo: {bar: "a"}}, {foo: {bar: "b"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok suppose I have a little more complex object like this:

```js
{
  root: {
    method: "ping",
    success: 1,
    error_code: 0,
    error_text: null,
    params: {
      foo: 11,
      bar: [
        {
          id: 62278639526,
          success: 1,
          error_code: 0
        },
        {
          id: 96176048010,
          success: 1,
          error_code: 0
        }
      ]
    },
    response_id: "b33ba904",
    time: 1681373894,
  }
}
```

I haven't found a way how to convert the js object to xml to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <method>ping</method>
   <success>1</success>
   <error_code>0</error_code>
   <error_text />
   <params>
      <foo>11</foo>
      <bar>
         <id>62278639526</id>
         <success>1</success>
         <error_code>0</error_code>
      </bar>
      <bar>
         <id>96176048010</id>
         <success>1</success>
         <error_code>0</error_code>
      </bar>
   </params>
   <response_id>b33ba904</response_id>
   <time>1681373894</time>
</root>
```

instead I always get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <method>ping</method>
   <success>1</success>
   <error_code>0</error_code>
   <error_text />
   <params>
      <foo>11</foo>
      <bar>
         <id>62278639526</id>
         <success>1</success>
         <error_code>0</error_code>
         <id>96176048010</id>
         <success>1</success>
         <error_code>0</error_code>
      </bar>
   </params>
   <response_id>b33ba904</response_id>
   <time>1681373894</time>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to convert your *more complex example* as you want, unless you add a key in *'params'*, but it's not the same thing:

```
{
   "root":{
      "method":"ping",
      "success":1,
      "error_code":0,
      "error_text":null,
      "params":{
         "foo":11,
         "bar":[
            {
               "bar":{
                  "id":62278639526,
                  "success":1,
                  "error_code":0
               }
            },
            {
               "bar":{
                  "id":96176048010,
                  "success":1,
                  "error_code":0
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "response_id":"b33ba904",
      "time":1681373894
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

exactly it's not the same thing, then I'll have this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <method>ping</method>
    <success>1</success>
    <error_code>0</error_code>
    <error_text />
    <params>
        <foo>11</foo>
        <bar>
            <bar>
                <id>62278639526</id>
                <success>1</success>
                <error_code>0</error_code>
            </bar>
            <bar>
                <id>96176048010</id>
                <success>1</success>
                <error_code>0</error_code>
            </bar>
        </bar>
    </params>
    <response_id>b33ba904</response_id>
    <time>1681373894</time>
</root>
```

so I'm not sure, if what I want is possible with this library. I just wanted to make sure if there's any solution. If not it's okay and I can find some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I need pass oneListGroup as true in XMLBuilder

```
const builder = new XMLBuilder({
  format: true,
  oneListGroup: true
});
```